# Can't update GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Yesterday I enlarged the system partition using gparted. Everything went fine, I rebooted and everything worked. This morning after turning on and selecting linux from bootlader - it does not turn on. I read that I should update GRUB, I use boot-repair with live-usb for this. Unfortunately the operation failed I'm getting [these errors](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m9qKbHRzXv/).

I also tried to repair and reinstall grub using a live USB according to [this link](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).  I get the same error which is shown in the boot-repair log:

```
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1: invalid ELF header
```

How can I fix this and is it a fault of enlarging the partition or just a coincidence? What I'm curious about is that yesterday everything was working.

Comment: If you see the expected Grub menu then whatever happens after any selection from there is NOT a Grub problem. Reinstalling Grub / using Boot-Repair isn't applicable. Can you boot an older kernel?

Comment: "Locked-NVram detected." Check your UEFI settings. Some systems have a way to prevent updates in UEFI. But you show grub2win, not grub in UEFI and a linpus UEFI entry.